# How to customize the colors of Ruby pry gem?

Tags: ruby, colors, pry

See the below image. I want to know whether there is a way to change the colors? Thanks.

[image]

---

Edit:

My OS is Win7 64 bit enterprise. I'm using Pry in a PowerShell command line windows, which was set black background.

[image]

Comment: Hello. What is your terminal or how do I reproduce your problem? :-)

Comment: Hi kyrylo, I'm using a Powershell command line. See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the more detailed description. I'll see what I can do tomorrow.

Comment: I just released a new pry-theme with Windows support. However, the Windows terminals are too limited, so Windows compatible themes don't look very pleasant. But if you know of a way to use 256 colorus in your Windows terminal, you'll be able to use all the beautiful themes. Cheers. https://github.com/kyrylo/pry-theme

Answer (score 3):

Try this gem, or try aproach they used in this gem https://github.com/kyrylo/pry-theme

Comment: Thanks Kukul. Sadly it does not support Windows. The author said: I hope it runs on Windows too, but I couldn't find any sane terminal, that would support 256 colors. Sorry, Windows guys.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers)